# Remove kendo grid header borders

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have to apply a particular style on the kendo grid headers. I did come across

> headerAttributes

in the kendo documentation which I tried getting to use here to make the background white and the font to the required but I am not able to remove the borders accompanying the header. Anyone can help me with an idea to get the same implemented. Including the dojo that I created to demonstrate a similar case

http://dojo.telerik.com/OXUTE

Edit: This is the kind of end result I am looking for

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which borders? The top and left border belong to the grid itself not the header, the bottom border belongs to the k-grid-header not the header cell, and the right border belongs to k-grid-header-wrap.  This will require multiple styles to accomplish.  The headerAttributes are applies to only each and every th, *not* to all the other elements whose styles are applying borders.

Comment: @TheDreadPirateStephen: I am actually looking for hiding these borders itself(the left,right and top mapped to the grid header).

Comment: To add on I have only 1 column of data here

Answer (score 1):

This is not pretty...because of the borders all belonging to different elements and the top-right grey corner needing to be gone, but this works:

```
.k-grid-header-wrap {
  border: 0;
}
.k-grid-header {
  padding-right: 0px !important;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-color: #fff;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-left-color: #fff;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-right-color: #fff;
  margin-left: -1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-right: -1px;
}
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/ErORO

It adds a border to the header that is the same colour as the background and then sets the margins to -1px so that the border is *on top* of the grid's border.  Otherwise, you have to figure out how to remove just the portion of the grid's left/right border on the top row without removing it from the rest of the grid.

It also forces the right padding to 0 to get rid of the grey block.

It works...but I feel dirty.

**Update...I was thinking about it some more**

Instead of hacking the borders off the header row, another way would be to completely hide the header and "replace" it with a label styled however you want, i.e.:

```
.k-grid-header
{
    height: 0;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/UWoZU